# Dynamic Logstash configuration

Tags: perl, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

Is it possible to configure logstash such that it updates all the input log paths dynamically?

My requirement is that whenever the file is created, my Perl script will notify the path where logs are generated

```
  #!/use/bin/perl

  use strict;

  my @cmd = `find /var/vob -type d -iname rtl2gds`;
  open (OFH, ">/var/vob/rtl2gds/icc_shantesh/input_dir_list") or die ("unable to open file writing $!");
  print OFH @cmd;
  close OFH;
```

I am getting the list of directories containing the required logs, and I need to feed them as input to the logstash configuration.

Is it ok if I set up a cron job to update the logstash config file and then take a restart?

I also need a filter which gives me key value pairs from my logs

### sample entries from logs

```
 ### Job is running on host vihlc1408 ###
 ### Total Number of CPUs: 24
 ### cpu MHz        : 2600.000
 set PREVIOUS_STEP plan
 plan
 set CURRENT_STEP  power
 power
 puts "\n#### Create new library ${MW}/${DESIGN}_lib_${CURRENT_STEP} and     open\n"
```

I am interested in picking CPU MHz, PREVIOUS_STEP and CURRENT_STEP, and then feeding it to Elastic search.

Comment: You are asking too many things in one question. And it's looking like your question is off-topic anyway, as Stack Overflow is primarily about helping to fix bugs in existing software, and you don't appear to have any software to fix

Comment: @Bordin Sorry i will chunk down my question. and i was asking for suggestion on how better i can establish the setup

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend edit the perl script to create soft link for each new path found in a folder like `/opt/log/` where logstash has read access.

Then add logstash `file` input filter with wildcard `path` to use this directory.

```
path =>"/opt/log/**/*"
```

This will check inside the `/opt/log/` recursively and read the log file.

Don't know if this is optimal but will work I think.